# Firefox connection problems

Tags: firefox, internet, connection

I am using Firefox on my Windows 8. When I first open Firefox, it waits a certain amount of time (30-60 sec) before it loads pages. When I put the laptop into sleep and open it again, it again shows the same symptom, this time loading nothing. It just shows loading bar until it times out. I have to close it completely (losing all tabs and sessions) and open it again. I checked the connection settings of Firefox, "Use system proxy settings" is selected.

What is the problem with Firefox? Other browsers work smoothly.

Comment: Are other browsers also using the system proxy settings? (I would assume so, but please make that explicit).

Answer (score -1):

Mine is similar in Win7 although it does not time out. With add-ons disabled it comes up almost instantaneously so you could try that. "Help" / "Start with add-ons disabled".